Getting ApplicationUser in BlazorServer page
I'm trying to access ApplicationUser of current logged-in user in Blazor Server .NET 8 app. I've added a new page in /Account/ISP called Index.razor
@page "/Account/ISP"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using WebApp.Components.Account.Shared
@using WebApp.Data

@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject IdentityUserAccessor UserAccessor
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager
@inject ApplicationDbContext DbContext


@code {
    private ApplicationUser user = default!;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
    }
}

Here I'm trying to replicate the logic of getting my user in Account/Manage, where it works nice from created Blazor template. After logging-in, I'm clicking the menu item to navigate to this page, and here I get NullReferenceException without stack trace. What did I do wrong?

"httpcontext" is only available in SSR rendermode. Its value is null when using InteractiveServer. If you check the template you will find it sets all pages which starts will "accounts" to SSR rendermode in App.razor like following:
...
<Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
...
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}

(When the render mode set to null, it is using SSR)
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#area-folder-of-static-ssr-components
